# Parametrize on() function jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have different user inputs. When one of them is changed I want to capture a change event only to its value.
I'm trying to customize the code of an existing product. My goal is to pop up an error div when user input is wrong but my current code adds the error div under all inputs.
This code works on all inputs but I want that it works only on input has title of label parent that contains 'Valore'.

JS CODE:

```
$(document).on('focusin', 'input', function () {
   $(this).data("oldvalue", this.value);
});
$(document).on('change', 'input', function () {
   var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.binf-form-group');
   if ($.isNumeric(this.value)) {
       $formGroup.find('.binf-help-block').remove();
   } else {
       this.value = $(this).data("oldvalue");
       $('<div class="binf-help-block" role="alert" style="white-space: normal;margin-top: 8px;background: #fff;color: #df3324;font-size: 11px;line-height: 16px;border-radius: 2px;border-left: 2px solid #df3324;padding: 0 8px;box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);">This value must be a number.</div>').appendTo($formGroup).fadeOut(3000, function () { $(this).remove()});
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="csui-field-text alpaca-container-item" data-alpaca-container-item-index="6" data-alpaca-container-item-name="4333_35" data-alpaca-container-item-parent-field-id="alpaca44">
    <div class="binf-form-group alpaca-field alpaca-field-text alpaca-required binf-has-error alpaca-invalid" data-alpaca-field-id="alpaca58">
        <label class="binf-control-label alpaca-control-label binf-col-sm-3" for="alpaca58" id="alpaca58Label" title="Valore">
           <span class="alpaca-icon-required binf-glyphicon binf-glyphicon-star"></span>
           Valore
        </label>
       <div class="binf-col-sm-9">
           <div class="alpaca-control">
               <div id="alpaca583195" class="cs-formfield cs-textfield cs-formfield-invalid">
                   <div class="cs-field-write">
                       <div class="cs-field-write-inner">
                           <input type="text" id="alpaca58" maxlength="32" placeholder="Add text" value="" aria-labelledby="alpaca58Label" aria-required="true" tabindex="-1">
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where do you want the alert to be appeared ?

Comment: @MajidAli My goal is to pop up an error div when user input is wrong but my current code adds the error div under all inputs.

Comment: Yes that's because you are appending your alert to the form at `$formGroup`, and what exactly do you mean by pop up ?

Comment: I mean to display an alert div under wrong field. I need to capture a change event only on input that has a parent label with title that contains 'Valore' -> $('input').closest('.binf-form-group').find("label[title*='Valore']").siblings('.binf-col-sm-9').find('input').attr('id') but I don't know how pass it to on() function

Comment: So you want to display that error message under that field for which a label contains the attribute title equal to valore ?

Comment: You can add that check inside the on. When changed check if its label contains that title then display that message, otherwise let it go.

Comment: the label must contain word 'Valore' because I have an interface with ten inputs but only on four inputs this code should work.

Comment: @MajidAli I add an image for you. Can you write code please?

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function () {
   var title = $(this).closest(".binf-form-group").find("label").attr("title");
   if(title.indexOf("Valore") >= 0){
     var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.binf-form-group');
     if ($.isNumeric(this.value)) {
         $formGroup.find('.binf-help-block').remove();
     } else {
         this.value = $(this).data("oldvalue");
         $('<div class="binf-help-block" role="alert" style="white-space: normal;margin-top: 8px;background: #fff;color: #df3324;font-size: 11px;line-height: 16px;border-radius: 2px;border-left: 2px solid #df3324;padding: 0 8px;box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);">This value must be a number.</div>').appendTo($formGroup).fadeOut(3000, function () { $(this).remove()});
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: not work because title must be containg 'Valore'! it can be 'Valore Oggetto' or 'Valore Casa' not only 'Valore'